# Connecting IBM MQ from a Standalone program | Error: ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect a queue manager from a standalone program and am getting the following error.

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
```

I understand that the connecting ID needs to be configured at the MQ to allow this connection.

But strangely, when I try to connect from Websphere Application Server (WAS), I am successfully connected to the queue.
My standalone program is using the same JDK as WAS.

Should the JVM ID for both these programs be the same?

I am using a CCDT file to connect to the queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it is authorization error on client connection. No doubt about that. See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21166937) for troubleshooting technote.

For start make sure that user which are you using is given proper rights (it isn't). Make sure that you are not using MQ administrator account with WMQ v7.1 or newer. 
Since 7.1 MQ Administrators are not allowed to create client connection with default configuration. This default can be changed. See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21577137).

One option is to use MCA user on client channel. This overrides whatever user you are passing. It is explained [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzas.doc/sy10910_.htm).

WAS is either using different user or bindings connection mode.

Comment: To add to this answer (thanks for referencing that Technote, by the way) the ID sent by the Java/JMS WMQ client depends on which version you are using.  But trying to get the client to send the right ID is counter-productive.  If you allow the client to set the ID then the value used to authorize the connection can change and cause an auths failure.  Better to arrange at the QMgr to set the desired `MCAUSER` value based on the certificate DN (best), the IP address, or the map the ID passed by the client, but only a validated and legitimate one from an enumerated list, to a static value.

Comment: Mapping the client ID is like the `MCAUSER` setting mentioned in the answer but uses `CHLAUTH` rules to dynamically map to or from any number of values.  Also, if WMQ Explorer is used be sure to install [SupportPac MS0P](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0P) and enable authorization events. This tells you the API call that failed, the object involved, the user ID making the call and the exact options used.  This helps to debug auths errors so you know, for example, that it is the `OPEN` and not the `CONNECT` that failed or vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for the response. We are indeed using the QMgr side authorization. It is just that I was running the standalone program with another User. I added this to the permissions list and it resolved the issue.